# SQL get value from XML in tag, by tag value

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have the following XML:

```
<Main>
    <ResultOutput>
        <Name>TEST1</Name>
        <Value>D028</Value>
    </ResultOutput>
    <ResultOutput>
        <Name>TEST2</Name>
        <Value>Accept</Value>
    </ResultOutput>
    <ResultOutput>
        <Name>TEST3</Name>
        <Value />
    </ResultOutput>
</Main>
```

What I want is to get the value of the `<value>` tag in SQL.

Basically want to say get `<value>` where `<Name>` has the value of `TEST1`, as an example

This is what I have at the moment, but this depends on the position of the XML tag:

```
XMLResponse.value(Main/ResultOutput/Value)[5]', nvarchar(max)')
```

Comment: Why are you declaring all those namepaces, when your XML contains no namespaces?

Comment: Please edit your post and add your real XML with all the namespaces, SOAP Envelope, etc.. Otherwise, it is impossible to help you. You already received two answers just by guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is not to put extra `where .value` clauses, but to do it directly in XQuery.

Use `[nodename]` to filter by a child node, you can even nest such predicates. `text()` gets you the inner text of the node:

```sql
XMLResponse.value('(/Main/ResultOutput[Name[text()="TEST1"]]/Value/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example using the sample XML in your question. You'll need to extend this to add namespace declarations and the proper xpath expressions that may be present in your actual XML as your query attempt suggests.

```
SELECT ResultOutput.value('Value[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
FROM @xml.nodes('Main/ResultOutput') AS Main(ResultOutput)
WHERE ResultOutput.value('Name[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') = N'TEST1';
```